# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown URL: content://media/external is hidden API

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have written a code to observe a change in the media images folder. I have written a MediaObserver class that extends ContentObserver. I am trying to get the RELATIVE_PATH and DISPLAY_NAME. But I am getting the exception when the contentResolver query runs. This issue i am facing for API level 29 and above. And register is called only after the read storage permission is given.

Crashlytics Exception is given below :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown URL: content://media/external is hidden API
   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2096)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderProxy.java:423)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:951)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:887)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:843)
```

Code to register the ContentObserver :

```
fun register(h: Handler?, context: Context): ContentObserver {
            val contentObserver = MediaObserver(h, context)
            context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, contentObserver)
            return contentObserver
    }
```

Code in onChange of the ContentObserver :

```
override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean, uri: Uri?) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH
        )

        context.contentResolver.query(
                uri,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null
        )?.use { cursor ->
               // Some code here
           }

    } else {
        // Some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: We're seeing the same problem.  Did you ever figure it out? 

The method gets called multiple times, so we're considering just catching the exception. We're still trying to reproduce it, but at least the first call has the IS_PENDING flag set, which we could safely ignore.

Comment: @jstock I could not figure out the solution for this. Yes, the method gets called multiple times. For that use the condition  if (cursor.moveToLast()) , inside this condition save the path in local variable and everytime check whether the path already detected or no.

Comment: Also posted on Google's IssueTracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279270031